# Subset/indices of array of objects based on object attributes

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Let's say  I have an array of objects like dummies[] below. I want to find the index of array objects where their attribute `a == 5` or `a > 3` etc.

```
class Dummy{
  int a;
  int b;
  public Dummy(int a,int b){
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
  }
}
public class CollectionTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Create a list of objects
      Dummy[] dummies=new Dummy[10];
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
          dummies[i]=new Dummy(i,i*i);
      }

      //Get the index of array where a==5
      //??????????????????????????????? -- WHAT'S BEST to go in here? 
  }
}
```

Is there any way other than iterating over the array objects and check for the conditions? Does using `ArrayList` or other type of `Collection` help here?

Comment: You will need to iterate through the array and add matching value `dummies` to a new array.

Comment: A simple iteration will let you find a given item, but a better question is why do you want the index? Or are you actually looking for the object that has `a==5`?

Comment: I need the indices because I am keeping a table of associations. There is a second array whic has objects which encompass only "a" variable. I need to match them with the objects in this array and do some calculations. a==5 is just an example. I have a range of values.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Example looking for a==5
// index will be -1 if not found
int index = -1;
for( int i=0; i<dummies.length; i++ ) {
   if( dummies[i].a == 5 ) {
      index = i;
      break;
   }
}
```